# PyQT Reading a text file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've been searching all over google and have found no solution, which is unbelievable! It should be simple. I'm trying to make my PyQT UI open a text file into a QTextBrowser or a QTextEdit.

But QTextEdit can't 'setSource' and QTextBrowser can not display anything but HTML, if I open the text file it doesn't have any of the paragraphing, it's all one line. This area will also display log files and I do NOT want my log files being output in html!

All I want to do is display the contents of a text file with plain text formatting. Why is this so stupidly hard??

Comment: `QTextBrowser` is an extended version of `QTextEdit` that allows hypertext links, unless you need that functionality, you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
text_edit = QPlainTextEdit()
...
text=open('file.txt').read()
text_edit.setPlainText(text)
```

Doesn't seem hard to me.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's hard when you don't know the commands and they don't seem to exist on google :/ If you know anywhere that actually lists them that'd be great, but anything I've found is uninformative, confusing, and rarely related to python.

Comment: @ Olen Prypin : I need the same, but I am not getting exact, please can you explore the above by giving small example where the window will contain the pushbutton and after clicking the pushbutton the text file should open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
    def openFileDialog(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File')

    if filename[0]:
        f = open(filename[0],'r')

        with f:
            data = f.read()
            self.textedit.setText(data)
```